# strange CSS issue

Tags: html, css

I have a popup panel which shows nice on chrome and FF like this:

[image]

It's a grey iframe with this css style:

```
element.style {
z-index: 25000;
opacity: 0.5;
position: absolute;
background-color: black;
border-width: 0px;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
width: 1366px;
height: 361px;
visibility: visible;
}
```

which contains a DIV:

```
element.style {
position: absolute;
z-index: 25001;
background-color: transparent;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 1366px;
height: 361px;
}
```

which contains another (main) white div:

```
element.style {
width: 400px;
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: hidden;
z-index: 25002;
visibility: visible;
position: absolute;
left: 483px;
top: 77px;
}
```

I do not understand **why on IE 8 the panel with those tabs is white also**, so basically it should be in the background like on Chrome...:

[image]

Do you have any clue?

I'm almost sure the problem is on the panel with the tabs and not on the popup one...

The css of the panel with the tabs is:

```
element.style {
width: 280px;
height: 500px;
position: relative;
}
```

**UPDATE:**

Panel tab is actually a table with the above style.

Ps: Do not blame me about css for the popup. Is mainly generated by the icefaces component.

Comment: set the `z-index` of panel tab to lower

Comment: Can these tabs have !important in their style ?

Comment: `element.style {
width: 280px;
height: 500px;
position: relative;z-index:-1000px
}`

Comment: Which version of IE? Which Document Mode are you using (hit F12 to bring up Developer Tools to find this out) Do you have anything we can look at online?

Comment: @Shakti If I put a lower index on pannel tab it does not show it at all...

Comment: @thirtydot I'm using IE8 and application is not yet online... About F12 tools I've already spent one hour with it on this issue...

Comment: How are the tabs controlled, and is that really all of their CSS?

Comment: @shanethehat  Panel tab is in a div without any style and thei are contained in a table. And yes, the table css is that all, it has other css for the content but I do not think that matters.

Comment: "I do not understand why on IE 8..." *Bangs head on desk*

Comment: [I'm good](http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a405015%20z-index) at fixing these types of problems, but I really need something to look at. Maybe you could create a "static version" of that single page that includes all the relevant CSS and JavaScript inline, and stick it on [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/). Just make sure the bug still happens.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, solved...

Added this style to the div which contains the panel tab:

```
position: relative;
z-index:-2;
```

Please note that I've tried with `z-index:0` or positive but was not working so a negative one was required...

The single drawback for this solution is that now, the parent div with its panel tab does not appear on Firefox.

Grr... I really hate IE.

**UPDATE**: I ended up using jQuery to put to that div, a negative z-index only for IE.

Comment: IE doesn't like `z-index:0`. It should work with any other value, though, depending of course on the other `z-index` settings around the page. If you need to do something specific for IE, you could use conditional comments for it rather than JQuery.

Comment: @Spudley Does this conditional comments works in css file? Because I do not want to put them inline or in my xhtml files.

Comment: No they don't. But the usual trick is to have a separate CSS file for IE, and include that using conditional comments.